# Calculate image rotation based on old and new positions of two points

Tags: matlab, face-recognition, image-rotation

I have images of faces in different positions. I want to rotate them, to make the line connecting the eyes always be horizontal. But I don't know how to do this in MATLAB.

And how can I calculate the angle of rotation?

Descriptive drawing of problem:

[image]

Comment: Automated? Or do you have only a few cases and you can just click on the eyes?

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: I have around.. 200 images. I do the work of manually click on the eyes of all the images, and save this info in a structure. So now, with this info of the position of the eyes, I have to rotate the images, to be all in horizontal.

Yes I have processing toolbox ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the locations of the eyes, then it's easy :) Here's an outline:

```
%//    left eye - right eye
pos = [  30          90    %// X
         80          40];  %// Y 

%// The angle equals the arctangent of dy/dx
angle = atan2(diff(pos(2,:)), diff(pos(1,:)));

%// Rotate in the opposite direction 
img = imrotate(img, -angle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can also look into the built-in landmark-based registration functions (especially if your transform is not limited to pure rotation), in particular [`cpselect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cpselect.html) with a syntax like:

```
cpselect(moving,fixed)
```

And then use `fitgeotrans` to construct the geometrical transform and `imwarp` to warp the moving image.